# Counting the inverter transition for its own function

Tags: javascript

I am writing a bot for google chrome in javascript and I have a problem, namely:

I check in intervale if the user has not disconnected. If he disconnected - skip it and open a new message. If not - I want to send specific messages in sequence. Unfortunately, but the repeating interval calls the same function over and over again, i.e. sendWelcomeMessage, when I want to stop this function after one interval and use another function.

I tried to bind a parameter to a function, but it does not work like I would like.

```js
function message() {

  var exists = document.getElementsByClassName("log-disconnected")[0].getAttribute("style");
  var nextBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("o-new-talk")[0];

  if (exists == "display: block;") {

    console.log("Stranger disconnected");
    nextBtn.click();

  } else {

    setTimeout(sendWelcomeMessage, 4000);

  }

}

setInterval(message, 3000);
```

Comment: `I want to stop this function after one interval and use another function.` then use `setTimeout` :)

Comment: Not sure on the ask here but if your intention is to `clearTimeout` on some condition, you can capture that in the very last line and use that in your logic. Also it probably seems math issue, every 3 secs `message()` gets called and `sendWelcomeMessage` call happens after 4 secs, by that time there will be one more `message()` invocation already happened.